# Trouble in displaying an image to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

I'm having a trouble in viewing or displaying an image from the database (mysql) to datagriview

The table in my database that I'm trying to retrieve is named as **sample** with fields **ID** = Int(10), primary, auto increment and **IMG** = blob

Anyone who can help me with this? It will be so much appreciated

```
Sub getData()
        Try
            Dim Sql = "Select ID, IMG from sample"
            connectionOn()
            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, ConOn)
            Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
            While dr.Read = True
                Dim mybytearray As Byte() = dr.Item("IMG")  
                Dim myimage As Image
                Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(mybytearray)
                myimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr(0), myimage)
            End While
            ConOn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Below is my code saving the image in the database. But it doesn't save anything. I want to get the image from the datagrid then save it to the database

```
Try
            connectionSync()
            Dim a, b As String
            Dim Sql = "INSERT INTO SAMPLE (ID, IMG)values(@a,@b)"

            For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                a = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, ConSync)


                Dim memorystream1 As New MemoryStream()
                Dim filename As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                Dim bitmaps As New Bitmap(filename)
                bitmaps.Save(memorystream1, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                Dim pic() As Byte = memorystream1.GetBuffer()

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", bitmaps)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            Next
            ConSync.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
               MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: First of all you shouldn't store image in your database. You can store them  on your server, then reference it using the location of image (store location of image in your database). Can you show your aspx as well?

Comment: @AmneshGoel i've been saving and retrieving images in database using longblob. i haven't saw any references in what your saying before so i saved it in database. i'm not having any problem but now that i need to sync my databases, i'm encountering such problems :(

Comment: @AmneshGoel and since what you're saying is prone to data loss, i didn't do it

Comment: can u show ur datagrid code from ur aspx?

Comment: @AmneshGoel actually, what i need to do is to sync , my first and second database. i only have a button and a datagrid in my form. the code above is my code for getting the data from the first database and displaying it to the datagridview.

Comment: I understand that from your code.. I want to see your aspx code for this data grid.

Answer (score 0):

Since [MySql BLOB Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-mssql-typemapping.html) is used to stored `SqlServer IMAGE Type` I think you can adapt this code using `MySql` classes (i.e.: `MySqlDataAdapter` instead of `SqlDataAdapter`):

```
Try

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

    Dim dgvID As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    dgvID.DataPropertyName = "ID"

    Dim dgvIMG As New DataGridViewImageColumn
    dgvIMG.DataPropertyName = "IMG"

    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvID)
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvIMG)

    connectionOn()

    Dim cmdSample As SqlCommand = ConOn.CreateCommand
    cmdSample.CommandText = "SELECT ID, " _
        & "IMG " _
        & "FROM Sample"

    Dim dtSample As New DataTable
    Dim daSample As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSample)
    daSample.Fill(dtSample)

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dtSample

    ConOn.Close()
    ConOn.Dispose()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: hi. thank you so much. i can now view the image in the datagrid. but do you also know how can i save it to another database? i can't save anything in the database :( i'll put the code of what i'm currently doing in my question

Comment: If `DataGridView1` is the same in the two code snippets then you have a `Byte()` and not a `String` in `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value`.